# .htaccess to rewrite static page to another page

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want www.example.com/blog.php to redirect to www.example.com/blog.php?post=welcome without breaking the .php script.

Simply redirecting /blog.php to /blog.php?post=welcome will break the file and return a page loading error.

I want /blog.php to immediately redirect to /blog.php?post=welcome, and want all the functions of blog.php to work as is.

I tried .htaccess rewrite code but its not working.

```
RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !blog.php$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blog.php?post=welcome [L,R=301]
```

Please help with the rewrite code.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know what `HTTP_HOST` means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog\.php$ %{REQUEST_URI}?post=welcome [L,R=301,NC]
```

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$ [NC]` ensures that redirect happens only when query string is empty this preventing a redirect loop.

Make sure to test in a new browser.

Comment: The problem with your code is, when I visit www.example.com/blog.php it redirects to http://example.com/C:/wamp64/www/blog.php?post=welcome instead of www.example.com/blog.php?post=welcome.plz help

Comment: If you use `%{REQUEST_URI}` in target URI as I have in my rule and keep this rule before any other rule then it will redirect fine. Make sure to clear browser cache or use a new browser.